# SQL query in Rails depending if params exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4 and MySQL. I have the following:

```
if params[:a].present? && params[:b].present? && params[:c].present?
  Shop.where("a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?", params[:a], params[:b], params[:c])
elsif params[:a].present? && params[:b].present?
  Shop.where("a = ? AND b = ?", params[:a], params[:b])
elsif params[:a].present?
  Shop.where("a = ?", params[:a])
else
  Shop.where("z = ?"), params[:z])
end
```

Writing this is simply not ideal because it's ugly. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Controller code:

```
if params[:a].present?|| params[:b].present? || params[:c].present?
   Shop.custom_search(request.POST)
else
   Shop.where("z = ?", params[:z])
end
```

Model code:

```
 def self.custom_search(params_hash)
    where(params_hash.slice("a", "b", "c"))
  end
```

I'm assuming if params  `a` and `c` are present, you'd want to return `a` and `c`. What you're essentially doing is grabbing the POST variables via `request.POST`, if any of the params are present, then putting it in a custom search algorithm located in your model code.

From there you're going to slice the params hash, putting the keys as the arguments of the specific key-value pair you wish to get.

If you didn't want specifically didn't want `params[:a]` and `params[:c]` to return anything at all you could just wrap the where in a `unless` statement, with the `key?` method checking on whether the params hash has both keys or not.

```
 unless params_hash.key?("a") && params_hash.key?("c")
    where(params_hash.slice("a", "b", "c"))
 end
```